# How can i transform a string like that 'AlÃ©m' in 'Além' in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a xml from a SOAP server, and the special characters comes like this 'AlÃ©m' how can i 'decode' it?

Comment: That is UTF-8 read as latin1 encoding if I am not mistaken. If you can't change the header encoding of the message, google for `chardet`, it can fix the `mojibake`.

Answer (score 0):

In python you can confirm what I said on my comment:

```
>>> 'além'.encode('utf-8')
b'al\xc3\xa9m'
>>> 'além'.encode('utf-8').decode('latin1')
'alÃ©m'
```

### Edit

I searched for a npm package that could do the same job as python's `ftfy` (fixestextforyou) package, but it seems there are none.

In python you can easily do this with the forementioned package:

On console:

```
$ pip3 install ftfy
$ python3
```

Then, as an example, on python session:

```
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 15:43:27)
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ftfy import fix_text
>>> fix_text('alÃ©m')
'além'
```

If you want to clean the text of file, you can paste the following into a `mojibake.py`:

```
from ftfy import fix_text

with open('your_txt_file.txt','r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    fixed_content = fix_text(content)
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as fw:
        fw.write(fixed_content)
```

(This will read from `your_txt_file.txt` and will output to `output.txt`, in same dir as you put the `mojibake.py`)

And call it from shell as:

```
$ python3 mojibake.py
```

Comment: he clearly asked for it in NodeJS environment

Answer (score 0):

This is a short and neat way to do it in NodeJS (or browser), from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68237082/3265448

```
const fixEncoding = s => new TextDecoder().decode(new Uint8Array(s.split('').map(r=>r.charCodeAt())))

> fixEncoding('AlÃ©m')
-> 'Além'
```